# ProxyPass in nginx

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, centos7

I am trying to proxy_pass in nginx with the following configuration:

`location /abc_service
{
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:3030;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}`

But I am getting /abc_service as prefix in my application(rails application running on port 3030). For Ex:
I am getting '/abc_service/users/sign_in' which should be '/users/sign_in'

*I want to remove this prefix.*

It was working fine in apache with :

`ProxyPass /abc_service http://localhost:3030 timeout=300 KeepAlive=On
ProxyPassReverse /abc_service/ http://localhost:3030/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation of `proxy_pass` is explained in nginx documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

> A request URI is passed to the server as follows:
>
> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the  server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:

```
location /name/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/;
}
```

> If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the > same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI:

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
}
```

So, you need to use this:

```
location /abc_service
{
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:3030/;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```